# conditional logic seeming not to work

Tags: properties, wix

I have a Wix Control PushButton which has several Publish events

here is the xml

```
<Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="0" Y="0" Width="50" Height="20" Default="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUINext)">
  <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="ErrorDialog">
    <![CDATA[PROPERTY1 = "1" AND PROPERTY2 = "1"]]>
  </Publish>
</Control>
```

But the dialog is not appearing even though both properties are equal to 1

Comment: I did put a closing </Control> node in but SO doesn't seem to want to show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found the problem pretty much straight after i posted. So am putting it here incase anyone else makes the same mistake i did.

Straight after my publish event i had another event which was getting fired to move onto the next dialog screen

```
<Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="CustomizeDlg">1</publish>
```

so even though my error dialog should show, this next event sort of overwrites it and you dont get to see it. to stop this happening i had to write in logic to prevent it from moving on.

```
<Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="CustomizeDlg">
<![CDATA[PROPERTY1 = "1" AND PROPERTY2 = "0"]]></Publish>
```

so now if both properties have been set it will show the error dialog, but if only the first one has been set i will move straight onto the CustomizeDlg. As long as the conditions are different and one will fail and the other pass this works a charm.